# I have trouble with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, persistence

I have two tables

Agenda

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "agenda")

public class Agenda {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idAgenda;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Consulta> consultas;
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Consulta")
public class Consulta {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int idConsulta;

@Column
private Calendar dataConsultas;

@Column
private  Time hora;

@ManyToOne
private Paciente paciente;

@OneToOne
private Colaborador colaborador;
}
```

when i run java its create third table called: agenda consulta. When i tried remove a consulta on table 'consulta' i do this:

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(consulta);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

but have error cause foreign. How do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to delete a consulta which is still referenced by an Agenda. So the foreign key constraint forbids you to do it, because it would make the database incoherent.

Make sure to remove references to the Consulta before removing it, by finding the agenda containing this consulta, and removing the consulta from the agenda's list of consultas.